# Difficulty retrieving pay slip from company CEO

Tags: job-offer, india, startup, payroll

Six months back, I used to work in a company which was a start up located in India. I left the company around April 2020 (during pandemic). Due to that I couldn't collect any certificates. After that, when the pandemic had died down, I gave a request to the CEO for experience certificate, relieving letter and pay slip. But the CEO didn't give pay slip, saying he will give it later. As I was unemployed at that time, I didn't follow up with him.

But after I left the company, I had a conversation with the new HR in that company in LinkedIn. During that conversation, I disclosed the faults of CEO and company. She being a sadist, conveyed what I told her in the conversation with her to the CEO. This infuriated my CEO and he said he will give a bad impression about me in my background review. After that, now I got an offer from a new company and they are asking for pay slip. I asked him for the same, but he has been delaying it for a week now giving me flimsy reasons like HR is not there or he is busy. The HR who had worked there has left the company. Even when I was working, usually HR's don't last more than 3 months and some of them come occasionally to the office. I don't even know whether there is a real HR there. How can I get the pay slip from CEO? If I file a complaint, what will happen if he gives a wrong background review about me? What is the ideal decision here, as I can't keep delaying the pay slip to new company (which I did convey to him).

Comment: `Due to that I couldn't collect any certificates`.. learning lesson: there's always soft copies  of document that can be sent over to avoid physical handling of documents.

Comment: Two things: can you please break it down into paragraphs? And second: what country are you in?

Comment: @Tymoteusz : I live in India

Comment: @TymoteuszPaul Given the relieving letter and payslip, it sounded like India already. :)

Comment: @SouravGhosh yep, likely, but doesn't hurt to clarify!

Comment: @TymoteuszPaul Absolutely, I was just guessing.

Comment: Answerers please note that India has very specific norms surrounding needing relieving letters and pay slips and such that are very unusual in the West (and, to be honest, very anti-worker).  Answers not aware of the specific Indian restrictions around these will not be helpful.

Comment: "I disclosed the faults of CEO and company": what did you hope to achieve by doing this?

Comment: if your new employer is adamant in getting your pay info rather than payslip, try to provide bank statement with the salary credit info and also your pf statement. That is in case you are unable to get the payslip

Answer (score 3):

I think you should tell the company, you got offer from, that previous workplace is not releasing it.

If you got the offer, they are obviously interested in you.

And, if pay slip is needed for some compliance purposes, they can drag it from your previous employer.

In my opinion, if he get official request for your pay slip from company, not a person, it would be much harder for him to withhold it

Answer (score 0):

I exactly don't know what / how "filing a complaint" works in your country, but if it

- gets you the required docs / certificates
- and those docs are a must to join the new job

then go ahead and file a complaint (or pursue whichever formal way you need to to obtain the required docs).

Regarding the background review: In majority, the new company will ask about the employment tenure and confirm your employment, nothing more than that. If the CEO/ the company lie about that, they can face legal recourse, so most likely they'll be truthful. So, your background check is covered.

One thing, you will not be able to list the CEO as your reference - find out someone else who can give you a positive review and talk about good things about you and your work.

Comment: This is different in India, because IIRC you’re not legally allowed to work two jobs at once, and your previous employer needs to give you a relieving letter before you can go work at a new employer.